# TLS 1.1 disabled for Office 365 services - will this affect Active Directory services for user management?

Tags: 2013-sp1, user-management

We use Active Directory for pulling in Tridion 2013 SP1 CMS users on our domain.

Will TLS 1.1 being disabled, and us connecting to ADFS, will that affect our ability to connect to Active Directory to manage users after 1st of March 2018?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4057306/preparing-for-tls-1-2-in-office-365

Answer (score 0):

you need to put this entry on your server to solve this TSL issue

Make the following changes in your Registry and it should work:

1.) .NET Framework strong cryptography registry keys
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

2.) Secure Channel (Schannel) TLS 1.2 registry keys
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001

Regards
Abhijit Angre

Comment: seems like your answer the last entry was duplicated.